# Create Log4j xml log file

Tags: java, xml, log4j

I'm using log4j for my logging purposes and all my log files in .log format, which is simply structured like;

> INFO [2012-05-08 09:57:57,919] [main] create table Employee passed.

I have heard that the logfile can be outputted in an xml format but coudn't find the exact configuration.

> log4j.rootCategory=INFO, C, R
>
> log4j.appender.C = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>
> log4j.appender.C.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>
> log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern = %5p [%d] [%t] %m%n
>
> log4j.appender.R = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
>
> log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>
> log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern= [%d] [%t] %5p %c %x - %m%n
>
> log4j.appender.R.File   = logs/test_suite.log
>
> log4j.appender.R.DatePattern = '.'yyyyMMdd

Comment: Not to mess with your question but if you start a new project, I suggest you take a look at slf4j which is log4j modern successor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLLayout`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/XMLLayout.html) as an appender layout. This creates log entries in the `<log4j:event />` tag.

I believe that this `Layout` is introduced from Log4J 4.2.16 and upwards, but I might be wrong.